# Eclipse Plugin Build Path Issues - Missing Required Libraries

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, buildpath

I am facing build path issues while trying to use an old Eclipse plugin called jrmtool_v1.0.0 on Eclipse SDK 4.3 for Linux (gtk-x86_64). The errors I am encountering are as follows:

```
1\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jface.text_2.1.0/jfacetext.jar'

2\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jface_2.1.0/jface.jar'

3\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32_2.1.0/ws/win32/swt.jar'

4\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.text_2.1.0/text.jar'

5\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.draw2d_2.1.1/draw2d.jar'

6\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.core.boot_2.1.0/boot.jar'

7\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources_2.1.0/resources.jar'

8\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core_2.1.0/jdtcore.jar'

9\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.views_2.1.0/views.jar'

10\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_2.1.0/workbench.jar'

11\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.editors_2.1.0/editors.jar'

12\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_2.1.0/runtime.jar'

13\. Project 'eclipse jRMTool4' is missing required library: '/home/akhil/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_2.1.0/texteditor.jar'

14\. The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved.
```

Can someone provide guidance on how to properly resolve these build path errors and successfully use the jrmtool_v1.0.0 plugin with Eclipse SDK 4.3?

Comment: Those all appear to be from Eclipse 2.1.0 which is 21 years and 37 releases old. It is going to be a major effort to make that work with Eclipse 4.3 (which itself is 11 years and 27 releases old). All releases of Eclipse are available on the [archive site](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/)

Comment: I downloaded eclipse-SDK-2.1-linux-gtk in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. But when I run on eclipse executable file, 
akhil@KHUSHI:~/Downloads/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse$ ./eclipse
./eclipse: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. I see this error.

Comment: Eclipse 2.1 will be 32 bit and using some old version of GTK so is very unlikely to run on a modern system. If you have the source of this jRMTool4 plugin you may be able to get it to run on a modern Eclipse otherwise this is probably close to impossible.

Comment: The code is present here: [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrmtool/). Can i install it in recent eclipse versions

Comment: Well the source is there so it might be possible. But I'm not about to example a large project to see what needs to be changed.